# Getting org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device - exception on 64-bit machine using SMSLib

Tags: java, rxtx, smslib

I wrote a code to send/receive sms via GSM Modem using SMSLib. On my 64-bit machine I set up 32-bit JDK as per solutions given in some links.

Following is code in which I am getting exception

```
 OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
            System.out.println("Please wait...");
                        gateway = new SerialModemGateway("s3.com3", comPort, 115200, "SAMSUNG", "S3");


            gateway.setInbound(true);
            gateway.setOutbound(true);

            System.out.println("gateway - "+gateway.getSmscNumber());

                        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);

            Service.getInstance().startService();
```

Now I am getting following exceptions trying with different devices attached with my machine's port.
For device-1(Samsung S3) I am getting following exception:

```
org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver$CharQueue.get(AModemDriver.java:535)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:338)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:313)
    at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler.getSimStatus(ATHandler.java:145)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:132)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

For device-2(Samsung Galaxy Note 2) I am getting following exception:

```
org.smslib.GatewayException: GSM: Invalid CREG response.
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.waitForNetworkRegistration(AModemDriver.java:463)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:168)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

Please suggest me some answers.

Sorry if I did any mistake in posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

The smslib does not support to samsung s3 and note 2
i tried with Samsung galaxy grand 2, it was working fine.
You also try with Samsung galaxy grand 2